# Is it possible to add new folder and files in patch?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, installshield, msp

We need to add new folders and files to existing release.

We know that adding new files is possible through patch [msp].

[For process related reasons they do not want to go minor upgrade]

But is it possible to add new folders also via msp?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure. You can add components to a feature during a patch and that component can have a CreateFolder element.

Comment: Thanks . i have referred the wix book and did it. your answer was starting point

Comment: But adding new components to a feature requires reinstallation of that (whole)feature when patching and so requires the original source msi file. See Community Additions section of [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367850%28v=vs.85%29.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367850%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: So cache the original MSI when you first install it.  He asked if it is possible and it is.  The other rule to be aware of is to design and test your servicing strategy *BEFORE* you ship your product.  There are also other tricks out there such as creating a new feature.